# Exception in deploying Application: Spring Data JPA + JBOSS EAP 6.3.0 on SUSE Enterprise Linux 12

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, suse

We are migrating from SUSE Enterprise Linux 11 to 12. We have a Spring Data JPA application deployed in JBOSS EAP 6.3.0 this is throwing the below error when enabling the deployment in JBOSS.

**Error:**

```
15:13:13,108 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMapppingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl.findAnnotation(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) [spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) [spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl.findAnnotation(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl.isAssociation(JpaPersistentPropertyImpl.java:133) [spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.AbstractPersistentProperty.<init>(AbstractPersistentProperty.java:62) [spring-data-commons-core-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.AnnotationBasedPersistentProperty.<init>(AnnotationBasedPersistentProperty.java:51) [spring-data-commons-core-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl.<init>(JpaPersistentPropertyImpl.java:87) [spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaMetamodelMappingContext.createPersistentProperty(JpaMetamodelMappingContext.java:77) [spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaMetamodelMappingContext.createPersistentProperty(JpaMetamodelMappingContext.java:38) [spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:390) [spring-data-commons-core-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:579) [spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:281) [spring-data-commons-core-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:246) [spring-data-commons-core-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.initialize(AbstractMappingContext.java:346) [spring-data-commons-core-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:73) [spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:26) [spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        ... 23 more
```

> **System Settings:**
>
> JBOSS EAP 6.3.0
>
> Oracle JDK 1.8.0_31
>
> spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
>
> spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar
>
> **Working on OS: SUSE EL 11**
>
> ***Not Working on OS: SUSE EL 12***

This is a clean Linux Installation, only with JDK 1.8 & JBOSS with no additional libraries added to JBOSS. No other applications deployed in the JBOSS except this one war file.

Any Help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved:**
The issue is resolved with version of Spring Data JPA 1.8.0 RELEASE.

*Changelog in version 1.8.0.RC1 (2015-03-05)*

**DATAJPA-664 - JpaPersistentProperty.getActualType() should consider specialized association type.**